# How to reduce the size of the mat pagination contents in Angular 16

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular16

I am using Angular 16. In that used the Angular Material component of 'Pagination'. It showing larger in size. So far I have tried some CSS workarounds to get it smaller.

```css
.mat-mdc-paginator-range-label {
   margin: 0 !important;
}
.mat-mdc-paginator-page-size-select {
  width: 57px !important;
}
.mat-mdc-option{
  font-size: 10px !important;
  min-height: 30px !important;
}
.mdc-text-field--outlined{
  padding-right: 12px !important;
}
```

Current View:

[image: Current View]

Expected View:

[image: Expected View]

Comment: did you try putting the paginator inside a div and handle the height via css?